# set variable to ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS Access database which consists of 9 tables. Each one represents landfills that collect garbage. 
These tables contain several fields, the primary key being the date and the rest of the fields are the tonnage of garbage that are send to each landfill by several municipalities.
For example for the table landfill 1:

date          municipality 1       municipality 2

1/1/2014          50 tons            30 tons

The query I'm trying to create is find out how many tons of garbage each municipality sends to all the landfills at a specific date. 
The code should be sth like

```
SELECT Landfill_1.municipality_1,    Landfill_2.municipality_1,...,Landfill_10.municipality_1
FROM Landfill_1.date INNER JOIN Landfill_2.date ,..., INNER JOIN Landfill_10.date
WHERE Landfill_1.date=[Please select the date:];
```

My problem is that municipality 1 **should be a variable** so that I don't have to change it each time.

Comment: You mean you want to change the name of `municipality_1` field?

Comment: Yes, I mean if someone wants to use the same query for municipality_2 he shouldn't manually change it for each Landfill table (10 times)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpivot the source data. Record in each row only a single set of variables and incorporate the municipality and landfill identifiers into the key.

```
Landfill, municipality, date,     amount
1,        1,            1/1/2014, 50
2,        1,            1/1/2014, 30
```

Use the query

```
SELECT Landfill, municipality, date, SUM(amount)
    GROUP BY Landfill, municipality, date
```

to return the aggregate results and then pivot the result in either Access or in Excel.

Avoid data that is not normalised in the database to permit more general queries. The presentation of the results should not be the primary consideration for the database schema design.

This also extends to any number of landfills and municipalities with no further database schema changes.

Comment: Is there no other way? I don't see this solution as viable because I take the data from excel worksheets which allows me to easily copy and paste them to my database, if i follow your solution I'll have to manually type the data for about 10000 entries.

Comment: If the data is already captured in a fixed form, you can create an interim table to move it into Access. Then, use an `INSERT` query to move the data into the correct form. Ask that future data is collected in the correct form and provide PivotTables to the users in their workbooks so that they can continue to view the data in their preferred format.

Answer (score 0):

Append data from all tables to one single table with the added field: MunicipalityId. Fill this with 1 to 9 as from which table the record origins.

Use this field and the date field in a compound unique index.

Now you need one query only.